# Error in AppManifest with SharePoint App in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, manifest, sharepoint-2013

I have the following in my app manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="TestSharePointApp"
     ProductID="{08c44f45-d7ef-4c8f-b808-043a48f44bcf}"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0"
>
  <Properties>
    <Title>TestSharePointApp</Title>
    <StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
  </Properties>

  <AppPrincipal>
    <AutoDeployedWebApplication/>
    <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />
  </AppPrincipal>

  <AppPrerequisites> 
    <AppPrerequisite Type="AutoProvisioning" ID="RemoteWebHost" /> 
  </AppPrerequisites> 
</App>
```

I am getting the following error for the RemoteWebApplication element:

```
The element 'AppPrincipal' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' has invalid child element 'RemoteWebApplication' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.
```

I am using the SharePoint App project template. I am trying to create a high-trust app for an on-premise SharePoint app catalog

Any help with this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the line:

```
<AutoDeployedWebApplication/>
```

You would only use that line in an autohosted app, or the line below it in a provider-hosted app. You can only use one or the other in a single app manifest. Since you said you are creating a high-trust app for on-premises SharePoint, you want to use this line instead:

```
<RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />
```